Using daterangepicker to date range and single days without double clicks
I am working on a beach reservation system and I need a daterangepicker which allows users to select a date range. But, the problem is that if a user is interested in selecting only one date or just a single day, they need to double click which, as we know, is not a good user experience.
I've tried changing certain properties such as setting singleDatePicker: (true). However, after this change only a single calendar is shown instead of a range picker with two calendars. I want it to work for both date ranges and single days without double clicks.
This is the daterangepicker library I'm using: https://www.daterangepicker.com/#config
This is my example: https://jsfiddle.net/sjnyzv6h/2/
How can I make it so that users can choose a single day without double clicking?

Just FYI, putting text in to the markdown code formatting makes it very hard to read, please don't do that. Also, please include your code within the question - ideally within an executable snippet - not as a link to an off-site resource. I've fixed these problems for you in this question

With regard to your issue, that control requires the user to select separate start and end dates. If you select the same date for both start and end, then you have to click it twice. If you don't want that behaviour, then you will need to use a different control. I'd suggest perhaps using two separate fields for start and end date with single date pickers. When a 'start' date is selected, pre-populate the end date field with the same value. That way if the user is selecting one day it's already done, if they need to change the end date to something else, then they easily can do that

@RoryMcCrossan thanks for your answer how to achieve this any resource or something share with me?
